# Check cherry-pick in parent branch

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In this flow, is there any way to see if a commit was merged into dev? The issue is when cherry-picking occurs it creates a duplicate commit that gets merged, but can you still tell if the original commit was merged into master?

Merge into dev -> cherry-pick into master

This is being checked in a gitlab-ci pipeline to ensure that all merges into dev get merged into master.

Answer (score 1):

Not with 100% certainty.

You may check what shows up using `git log --cherry-mark master...dev` or `git log --cherry-pick master...dev` ([link to doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-mark))